# Retrieve an object which has a POJO as a primary key with Spring JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following classes: DepartmentMember and Account, mapped by a OneToOne relationship.

This is the DepartmentMember class:

```
@Entity(name="departmentmember")
@Table(name="departmentmember")
@Embeddable
public class DepartmentMember {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;

   @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
   private String nume;

   @Column(name="lastName", nullable=false)
   private String prenume;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy="departmentMember",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
   @JsonIgnore
   private Account account;

   public DepartmentMember() {}

   public DepartmentMember(String nume, String prenume, String cNP, String email) {
       super();
       this.nume = nume;
       this.prenume = prenume;

     }

  //getters and setters

}
```

And this is the Account class :

```
@Entity(name="users")
@Table(name="users")
public class Account {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name="authorities", nullable=false)
    private String authorities;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId
    @Embedded
    private DepartmentMember departmentMember;

    public Account() {}


    public Account(String username, String password, String authorities) {
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

//getters and setters
}
```

I have defined an interface AccountRepository which extends the CrudRepository interface provided by Spring JPA.
What I want to do is define a query, which takes as a parameter a DepartmentMember id and retrieves the associated account for that member. Now this is how an Account object looks like:

```
{
"username": "Maria_Popescu",
"password": "4ec38c6e-2463-4562-99ba-9f6c2b4528c4",
"authorities": "ROLE_USER",
"departamentMember": {
  "id": 2,
  "nume": "Popescu",
  "prenume": "Maria",
}
```

I tried using the findOne(int id) method, but it didn't work, so which is the correct approach to solve this?

**Edit:**
In the AccountRepository I have defined the following method :

Account findByDepartmentMemberId(int id) and I still get a not found error.

Comment: I'm a little confused from the above, are you sure that your mappings are correct? I don't think that  in Account DepartmentMember can be both Embedded and OneToOne.

Comment: @garfield I actually removed those later, but it didn't change the way things behaved. My query is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

There was actually another problem in my controller. I managed to get it working by adding

```
Account findByDepartmentMemberId(@Param("id")int id);
```

in the AccountRepository